# Bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard

Can the Bluetooth board "XS3868" be used for in a Bluetooth keyboard for a computer? Without using an Arduino
[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot. The OVC3860 controller ([datasheet](http://www.szriley.com/DownLoadFile/OVC3860.pdf)) that the XS3868 module is built around is specifically a Bluetooth audio controller — it has pins dedicated to functions such as a microphone input and two speakers. It cannot be configured to act as another class of Bluetooth device.

As a side note, the schematic you included in your question does not match with any of the typical pinouts I saw.

Comment: Sorry it was the only schematic I could find that was clean and was similar to the board I have. And is there a board where I could build a keyboard with?